# React-Native with Expo - Avoid the strange behavior of the keyboard on Android

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

I wrote the code at this [link](https://snack.expo.io/@foobanizer137/example) for create a login/signup page in `react-native` using `expo cli`. But, how can you see (if you try the demo) when the user click on the `TextInput` the kayboard is opened and all the grphical components are pushed on the top. 
You can see a simple result in the following image:

[image: Keyboard Behavior]

The test is doing on a Huawai P20 lite.
All the code is wrote using all version of the dependencies. The most important:

```
"dependencies": {
  "expo": "~37.0.3",
  "react": "~16.9.0",
  "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
  "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.0.tar.gz",
  "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
},
```

I try to resolve the problem wrapping the all UI with the component `<KeyboardAvoidingView>` with all possible combination of the `props` `behavior` and `keyboardVerticalOffset` but the problem persist.
I also try, before using the `<KeyboardAvoidingView>` wrap all into a `<ScrollView>` but I have always the same result.

At the last, I try to use some package that I fount on `npm` like:

- [react-native-set-soft-input-mode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-set-soft-input-mode)
- [react-native-android-keyboard-adjust](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-keyboard-adjust)
- [rn-soft-input-mode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-soft-input-mode)

But with all I have the same error:

> Type error: is not a function

How can I prevent this strange behavior (i remember that with the old version the problem does not exist) without run `expo eject` and editing the `AndroidManifest.xml`? There is a method for map the `xml` file in the `app.json` file? Or, there is a working module that I can use for avoid the problem?

Comment: You can track a related issue and see a workaround here: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/7635

Comment: @brentvatne Using the suggestion that I find on the github issue does not reolve the problem...